# What tools are available to export an ipython notebook to a PDF file?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a nicely-formatted ipython notebook complete with markdown cells and whatnot.  I'm wondering what my options are in terms of exporting to a PDF file.

So far, I've been going to `File > Print View` and printing the resulting page to PDF with chromium's "save to file" function.  This technically *works*, but it has one major inconvenience:   my figures, code and markdown cells are often split by page breaks.

Are there any other solutions for explort such that I can have one continuous PDF file?

**EDIT:**  I ran into [nbconvert](https://github.com/ipython/nbconvert), but when I keep getting a "file not found" error.  Anybody have any luck with nbconvert?  The documentation claims to support exporting to PDF, but when I ran `nbconvert.py -f pdf`, the error message suggested that the PDF format was not, in fact, supported.

Comment: Uh mods... I *did* describe the problem and the steps I took to fix it.  Methinks you read the title alone and not the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you cannot directly convert an ipynb into a pdf, so the error message is right!
You need to first convert it into latex: `nbconvert.py -f latex your_nb.ipynb` and then use `pdflatex your_nb.tex` to build the pdf file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you post a ultra-short tutorial on that? In particular something that shows a student how they can convert their ipython-notebook into a uni-compliant TeX-thesis. Thx in advance.

Comment: you can even use this : nbconvert.py -f latex --post pdf your_nb.ipynb

Comment: Since nbconvert is now part of IPython (since 1.0), you can use `ipython nbconvert --format latex --post pdf your_nb.ipynb`.

Comment: `ipython nbconvert --to latex nb.ipynb` -- Then I converted to pdf using a latex program. `--format` is depricated

Answer (score 14):

You can use ipython to do this, for instance the command:

```
ipython nbconvert notebookname.ipynb --to latex --post pdf
```

to convert notebookname.ipynb to a pdf. It does however require that you are running the latest version of texlive (that's texlive 2013) to have the supporting software. Note that Ubuntu 12.04 comes with texlive 2009 from their repositories. 2013 can be installed from CTAN directly, just follow [these directions](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). Then you are up and running, and it looks great.

Comment: I upvoted, but I believe this is only the case in recent ipython versions.  At the time this question was posted, this functionality did not exist (unless I'm horribly mistaken).

Answer (score 3):

IF all else fails as tex can be quite moody... install wkhtmltopdf

\i then use nbconvert to create a html, and then wkhtmltopdf to create the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

If you're converting notebooks often enough, [here is a script](https://gist.github.com/CloudCray/994dd361dece0463f64a) that uses wkhtmltopdf to convert a selected notebook into HTML and PDF. Once you've installed [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html), keep this script in the same folder as your notebooks and run it whenever you want to convert a notebook quickly.