# Convert IPython notebook to PDF

Tags: python-3.x, pdf-generation, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have written a very long IPython notebook and need to convert it to PDF for distribution. I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132213/what-tools-are-available-to-export-an-ipython-notebook-to-a-pdf-file) but the solution didn't work for me.

I've tried the following:

1. If I use the Print button in my browser, I have all the IPython menu
   etc. showing, which I can't accept.
2. If I use Print Preview from the IPython menu, none of the LaTeX equations render. They are all             still just LaTeX code.
3. If I use `ipython nbconvert --to latex --post pdf myfile.ipynb` I get a `FileNotFoundError`. Traceback follows:

```
[NbConvertApp] Using existing profile dir: 'C:\\Users\\blokeley\\.ipython\\profile_default'
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook myfile.ipynb to latex
[NbConvertApp] Support files will be in myfile_files\
[NbConvertApp] Loaded template article.tplx
[NbConvertApp] Writing 72246 bytes to myfile.tex
[NbConvertApp] Building PDF
[NbConvertApp] Running pdflatex 3 times: ['pdflatex', 'myfile.tex']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 564,
  launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 367, in start
    return self.subapp.start()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py",
  line 268, in start
    self.convert_notebooks()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py",
  line 311, in convert_notebooks
    self.postprocessor(write_resultes)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\postprocessors\base.py",
  line 28, in __call__
    self.postprocess(input)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\postprocessors\pdf.py",
  line 140, in postprocess
    cont = self.run_latex(filename)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\postprocessors\pdf.py",
  line 104, in run_latex
    self.latex_count, log_error)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\postprocessors\pdf.py",
  line 84, in run_command
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=stdout, stdin=null)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1111, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    c.Application.verbose_crash=True
```

I'm using the latest updates from Anaconda in Python 3.4 64-bit on Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: No. I'm on Windows. nbconvert is supposed to support PDF creation without LaTeX installed so it should not matter. On top of that, wouldn't installing LaTeX would be a real hassle - doesn't it need Cygwin and all that? I had hoped that we could use IPython to replace MATLAB but I'm not going to convince my colleagues to use IPython if it needs Cygwin and all manner of other stuff.

Comment: Point 2: update IPython to 2.3 we rushed the release of IPython 2.3 almost just for that.

Comment: No, nbconvert does not support pdf creation without latex, if you can point to where you read such a thing we can try to have it fixed. There might be one way though which is .ipynb -> .rst and then rst2pdf but it is not yet implemented.

Comment: I installed ipython 2.3 and at least nbconvert can convert to html with maths now, which is good enough for me. Thanks. I'll check out the PDF generation from Ffisegydd too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you do not have LaTeX installed on your computer. When `subprocess` tries to call `pdflatex myfile.tex` it therefore fails as it cannot find `pdflatex`.

Whilst it's true that you can create `.tex` files from IPython notebooks without needing LaTeX, these are just files that contain the LaTeX code. To compile them to create PDFs you need a version of LaTeX.

Installing LaTeX on Windows is not difficult, [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/) is one possible installation.

Comment: The other major option is to install using the texlive distribution. Given that MiKTeX (MT) installs by default just a minimal configuration (and later automatically installs further packages as requested by circumstances), given that texlive installs ~1GB of stuff, and given that the OP has no direct interest in TeX/LaTeX as yet, I'd second your suggestion of using MT rather than texlive.